# PHP do not repeat last fetch

Tags: php, mysql, fetch

I have this code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quote ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());  

$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );

echo $row['frase'];
```

It echo´s a random "frase" every time you query.

What I want to do is avoid having the same result in consecutive queries.

To make myself clear, if in my database I´ve got:

```
1   a
2   b
3   c
```

If from `echo $row['frase'];` I got `a` the the next result can´t be `a`.

I hope I made myself clear and if not please comment and I´ll expand!

Thanks in advance!

BTW: sorry to @deceze @zerkms @Dr.Molle because last question was a total mess! No harm ment, just a noob on a spree :)

**EDIT:**

To answer Jason McCreary I actually call it like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc()
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this query on page reload or used later in the script?

Comment: I edited my question. Is that cear now? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this last query needs to persist across page refreshes, you need to use a session. Something along these lines:

```
session_start();

if (empty($_SESSION['lastresult'])) {
    $_SESSION['lastresult'] = null;
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM `quote` WHERE `id` != '%s' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$query = sprintf($query, mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['lastresult']));

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());  

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$_SESSION['lastresult'] = $row['id'];

echo $row['frase'];
```

You may want to store the last x results in the session and use `NOT IN ()` in your query to avoid every second (third, forth, ...) quote being the same.

Comment: Thanks deceze I´m trying it out!

Comment: In terms of what you're doing, you should avoid using ORDER BY RAND() and instead calculate a random position between 0 and the number of results (or equivalent) and shuffle these in your application layer to avoid making mysql randomise the entire data set, then use that value in your query by asking for the first entry greater or lesser than that random value.  It's nicer on mysql and you can persist the data in the session, so you can speed up creating useful random positions to select from in mysql.